# Waves and forces

Tags: forces, waves

Does any and each wave has a force in the wave's direction?
In other words, do there any force act to push the wave in it's default direction?
Like what happened to material when it move?

Answer (score 0):

in a transverse wave case, the force will only act perpendicular to the wave direction. There is no force pushing the wave because it itself is not a particle of mass. In a longitudinal wave the force acts parallel to the direction but in both directions. In any case, it is not a force that carries the wave across a medium

Comment: What carried the wave then, if it's not the force, may you explain please?

Comment: well, i may have been unclear. A force is *required* to carry a wave. But it does not act in the direction of the energy transfer at *any* point in time in a transverse wave. So it does not push the wave so to speak

Comment: The force does not transfer any momentum in the wave's direction, which can be seen from the fact that particles remain in the same place as the wave  passes by

Comment: It does not have a force which carries it in any case

Comment: For energy to move, for example for a billiard ball to take off, there is need for a "force" at the impact point , and impulse  = dp/dt . After that it is Newton's first law of motion. "In an inertial reference frame, an object either remains at rest or continues to move at a constant velocity, unless acted upon by a force." .The same is true for waves.  The depend on various impulses ( dp/dt) to start them off, like a stone throw in the center of the lake, and then keep on depending on the physical forces of the medium ( potential and kinetic energy exchanges) .

Comment: See this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BTWiZ7CYoI

Comment: @annav That's technically a longitudinal wave which has stopped after traveling through pi/2 radians right? It doesn't really have sinusoidal or cyclical motion. In this case, there has been a force because the net momentum of the 'particles' has increased in the forwards direction. but you can't say that there's an overall driving force pushing the wave across can you? I think that is a misconception.

Comment: There is the original dp/dt which is a force, and then it is momentum and energy conservation depending on the medium

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE520z_ugcU), and others like it if you search for wave generation on youtube.

You can clearly see that the only force applied in this demonstration is at one time, t1, by twisting one stick, a dp/dt , instantaneous force is applied. The creation of the wave depends on the materials used, the disturbance travels by displacing the medium either longitudinally or trasversly and then the physical bonds of the medium transfer the motion and a wave is generated.

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9QwiBFN9gI) the impulse is when the stone hits the water, then sperical waves take off, by the elasticity of the medium, kinetic energy changing to potential energy as the wave spreads with the original momentum that was given by the dp/dt of the thrown stone.